# Minimal example of WCF using HTTPS

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to get a minimal WCF/https example working, but I can't access the service (surprisingly the code runs without errors).

- I have created a root certificate:

  > makecert -n "CN=Test" -r -sv Test.pvk TestCert.cer
- I have added it to the Windows-Root certificates.
- I have created a server certificate:

  > makecert -sk TestCom -iv Test.pvk -n "CN=TestCom" -ic TestCert.cer -sr LocalMachine -ss my -sky exchange -pe
- I have reserved a port for the SSL url:

  > netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:15001/ user=Everyone
- I have set the certificate hash to the port:

  > netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:15001 certhash=XXX appid={76d71921-b40d-4bc8-8fcc-4315b595878e}
- I have added TestCom to the etc/hosts file

Now I have created a simple C# project:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ISimpleService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string SimpleMethod(string msg);
    }

    class SimpleService : ISimpleService
    {
        public string SimpleMethod(string msg)
        {
            return "Hello " + msg;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SimpleService));
            try
            {
                host.Open();
                Console.ReadLine();
                host.Close();
            }
            catch (CommunicationException commProblem)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There was a communication problem. " + commProblem.Message);
                Console.Read();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with the following app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviors_HTTPSServiceHost" >
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_HTTPSServiceHost">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service name="ConsoleApplication7.SimpleService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviors_HTTPSServiceHost">
        <endpoint address=""  binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_HTTPSServiceHost"
                  contract="ConsoleApplication7.ISimpleService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="TestCom"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint name="mex" address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://TestCom:51001/SimpleService"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Do the user "Jeder" have read rights to the certificates private key?

Comment: Sorry, "Jeder" == "Everyone"

Comment: Here you are only hosting the service. You also need a client to call the service methods.

Comment: This is clear, if I try to open https://TestCom:51001/SimpleService in the browser nothing happens, if I try to open the URL with the WcfTestClient.exe it says can't access metadata ...

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on this account so please open a dialogue below if this isn't the answer and can help narrow it down. Cross reference your set up with what I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61760341/wcf-impersonation-with-wshttpbinding) and you might spot something in your set up that I did not.

Only concern that i can see initially is

> I have added it to the Windows-Root certificates.

```
A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.
```

If this is the error, just check you imported the cert to the correct location.

Importing an Existing Certificate

- Run mmc.exe.
- Go to File-> Add/Remove Snap-In
- Choose the Certificates snap-in.
- Select Computer Account
- Navigate to: Certificates (Local Computer)\Personal\Certificates
- Right click the Certificates folder and choose All Tasks -> Import.
- Follow the wizard instructions to select the certificate.

I have hit every issue possible with wsHttpBinding and have a personal wiki, I can help you better if there are any logs, where is it crashing at currently?

Answer (score 0):

Guess you need to include the policyVersion to make it run like below

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"  policyVersion="Policy12"></serviceMetadata>
```

Comment: If I change <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" /> to <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"  policyVersion="Policy12"/> 
the application crashes immediately, if I change it that way: 
<serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" policyVersion="Policy12" /> the problem still exists and nothing changes.